# Can I inspect a request from Ajax and will it have my Asp.net session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When some javascript makes a request to a .net page or reseource on a server can the server get access to the session that the client (sending the call) has?

Comment: yes - as far as the server is concerned, there should be no distinction between a user invoked request, or a javascript invoked request - as long as they are coming from the same client then the session should be available

Comment: Dave why didnt you put this in an answer?

Comment: Hi Pete - no specific reason - just clicked and typed :-) - have added my answer now.

Comment: okay was the most suitable answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - as far as the server is concerned, there should be no distinction between a user invoked request, or a javascript invoked request - as long as they are coming from the same client then the session should be available

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Cookies are sent for XMLHttpRequest messages.